# How to re load an different file in java after having printed a previous one

Tags: java

Ok So this code I have below is compiling  but I have a logic error. Ok so  After i enter the file with the data i would like it to read and I choose to print that data on screen I have the choice of loading a different file. However, when I do enter the name of the new file that I would like to load it does not load the file and the error message that I designated for that particular situation it outputted. I think i have to flush  the stream buffer after each write or something like that. So um if anyone can point of why this is happening then I would appreciate it.

import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class Driver {
    private static int numberOfCustomer = 0;
    private static Customer[] customerList = new Customer[10];

        private static void readInCustomer(String file){
        FileReader freader;
        BufferedReader inputFile;
        try{
            freader = new FileReader(file);
            inputFile = new BufferedReader(freader);
            String strLine;


            while ((strLine = inputFile.readLine()) != null)   {
                    customerList[numberOfCustomer] = new Customer();
                    customerList[numberOfCustomer].ID = strLine;
                    customerList[numberOfCustomer].name  =                 inputFile.readLine();
                    customerList[numberOfCustomer].address  = inputFile.readLine();
                    customerList[numberOfCustomer].phone  = inputFile.readLine();
                    numberOfCustomer++;
            }

            inputFile.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file "+file+" System will now exit");
            System.exit(1);

        }

        return;
    }

        private static void printCustomer(Customer customer){
        System.out.println("The Customer Data corresponding to Customer Number " + customer.ID  + " is:");
        System.out.println("Name:\t\t\t"+customer.name);
        System.out.println("Address:\t\t"+customer.address);
        System.out.println("Telephone:\t\t"+customer.phone);
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

        private static void printAll(){
        boolean hasID = false;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("All customers from data file "+numberOfCustomer);


        System.out.println(" Here they are!!! ");
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfCustomer; i++){
            if(customerList[i] != null){
                System.out.println("The Customer Data corresponding to Customer Number " + customerList[i].ID  + " is:");
                System.out.println("Name:\t\t\t"+customerList[i].name);
                System.out.println("Address:\t\t"+customerList[i].address);
                System.out.println("Telephone:\t\t"+customerList[i].phone);
            }
        }
        if(!hasID){

        System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to go to the menu? (Y or N):");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);
         if(repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y'){Menu();} 
                    return;
    }

    private static void Menu(){
        boolean hasID = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("YOU MAY CHOOSE FROM THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS:");
      System.out.println("A. SEARCH for a customer by ID number");
      System.out.println("B. DISPLAY the entire Customer List");
      System.out.println("C. RE-LOAD DATA from a different data file");
      System.out.println("D. QUIT:");

        String choice = keyboard.nextLine();

        char repeat = choice.charAt(0);
         if(repeat == 'A' || repeat == 'a'){Scostomer();} 
            if(repeat == 'B' || repeat == 'b'){printAll();}
            if(repeat == 'C' || repeat == 'c'){mainn();}
              return;

        }

   public static void Scostomer(){
    boolean hasID = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type in the Id you are search for");

        String customerID = keyboard.nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfCustomer; i++){
            if((customerList[i]!=null) && (customerID.equals(customerList[i].ID))){
                hasID = true;
                printCustomer(customerList[i]);
                i=customerList.length;
            }
        }

        if(!hasID){
            System.out.println("Sorry, customer not found.");
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to search for another custnomer? (Y or N):");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);
         if(repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y'){Scostomer();} 
            if(repeat == 'N' || repeat == 'n'){Menu();}
                    return;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the fileName that contains the data of your customers: ");
        readInCustomer(keyboard.nextLine());
        Menu();
        return;
        }

    public static void mainn(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the fileName that contains the data of your customers: ");
        readInCustomer(keyboard.nextLine());
        Menu();
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: try putting 'e.printStackTrace()` in catch block of `readInCustomer` and then hope you ll find the issue if not then put that trace with your question?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Check to make sure that you have the right file path and that you are typing it in correctly.

Comment: I the problem was that the second txt file i wanted to load had a longer string in in so i had to increase  private static Customer[] customerList = new Customer[10]; to private static Customer[] customerList = new Customer[30];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me (load a file, type c to load new file, type b to display all). I'd suggest there's something simple wrong (wrong filename or something silly), so you you'll want to log the exception details, instead of ignoring them in your catch block.

```
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // should tell you what's wrong!
        System.out.println("Could not find file "+file+" System will now exit");
        System.exit(1);

    }
```

Flushing is not relevant here as you are *reading*, not writing. You could probably tidy up the whole menu/input loop too, it's a bit wacky (but it works!). For example, your *main* and *mainn* methods are identical - have you considered abstracting that out into a separate method?

Instead of limiting yourself to 10 customers, you can use a List and not have to worry about how many customers you're going to read in (I've only changed your code to use a List instead of an array):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private static int numberOfCustomer = 0;
    // List instead of array!
    private static List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    private static void readInCustomer(String file) {
        FileReader freader;
        BufferedReader inputFile;
        try {
            freader = new FileReader(file);
            inputFile = new BufferedReader(freader);
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.ID = strLine;
                customer.name = inputFile.readLine();
                customer.address = inputFile.readLine();
                customer.phone = inputFile.readLine();
                customerList.add(customer); // add to the List!
            }

            inputFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + file
                    + " System will now exit");
            System.exit(1);

        }

        return;
    }

    private static void printCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out
                .println("The Customer Data corresponding to Customer Number "
                        + customer.ID + " is:");
        System.out.println("Name:\t\t\t" + customer.name);
        System.out.println("Address:\t\t" + customer.address);
        System.out.println("Telephone:\t\t" + customer.phone);
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    private static void printAll() {
        boolean hasID = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("All customers from data file " + numberOfCustomer);

        System.out.println(" Here they are!!! ");
        for (Customer customer : customerList) {
            System.out
                    .println("The Customer Data corresponding to Customer Number "
                            + customer.ID + " is:");
            System.out.println("Name:\t\t\t" + customer.name);
            System.out.println("Address:\t\t" + customer.address);
            System.out.println("Telephone:\t\t" + customer.phone);
        }

        if (!hasID) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to go to the menu? (Y or N):");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);
        if (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y') {
            Menu();
        }
        return;
    }

    private static void Menu() {
        boolean hasID = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("YOU MAY CHOOSE FROM THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS:");
        System.out.println("A. SEARCH for a customer by ID number");
        System.out.println("B. DISPLAY the entire Customer List");
        System.out.println("C. RE-LOAD DATA from a different data file");
        System.out.println("D. QUIT:");

        String choice = keyboard.nextLine();

        char repeat = choice.charAt(0);
        if (repeat == 'A' || repeat == 'a') {
            Scostomer();
        }
        if (repeat == 'B' || repeat == 'b') {
            printAll();
        }
        if (repeat == 'C' || repeat == 'c') {
            mainn();
        }
        return;

    }

    public static void Scostomer() {
        boolean hasID = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type in the Id you are search for");

        String customerID = keyboard.nextLine();

        // iterate over the List!
        for (Customer customer : customerList) {
            if (customerID.equals(customer.ID)) {
                hasID = true;
                printCustomer(customer);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasID) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, customer not found.");
        }
        System.out
                .println("Would you like to search for another custnomer? (Y or N):");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);
        if (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y') {
            Scostomer();
        }
        if (repeat == 'N' || repeat == 'n') {
            Menu();
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Enter the fileName that contains the data of your customers: ");
        readInCustomer(keyboard.nextLine());
        Menu();
        return;
    }

    public static void mainn() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out
                .println("Enter the fileName that contains the data of your customers: ");
        readInCustomer(keyboard.nextLine());
        Menu();
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks man! I have seen e.printStackTrace(); before nice It gave me this error   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Driver.readInCustomer(Driver.java:33)   so I just inscreaase the number from 10 - 30 and it worked

Comment: You should consider using a Collection (i.e. List) instead of an array if you can't guarantee you'll always have a maximum of 10 customers.

Comment: Note though, that printing to System.out (and using e.printStackTrace()) is generally frowned upon - logging frameworks such as commmons-logging, slf4j etc are recommended instead. But it's fine for quick and dirty logging, or for standalone command line applications.

Comment: Ok so what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Ahhh so using the list removes  some limitations ahhh ok thank you i will remember that Fromm now on you have helped me so much thanks